# Ram memory not freed after executing python script on ubuntu system

Tags: python, linux, memory, garbage-collection, ubuntu-18.04

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/poyQx.png)I am having a Ubuntu system which has 125 Gb of RAM. I executed few python scripts on that system. Those scripts uses numpy arrays and pandas. Now execution was over but still 50 gb of RAM and 2 Gb cache and 8.4 Gb of swap is occupied. At this moment nothing is running on the system. I have googled it. Most of th result shows that python garbage collector is poor in performance.  I want this memory to be cleaned  and re claim. One of the easiest way is to restart the system but i dont want to restart i want a way to do this when the system is up and running. Kindly tell me how to do this.
Thanks

Comment: If the execution is over and the `python` process is no longer running, then all its memory is already freed. Is `python` still running?

Comment: i have attached the image for your refrence

Comment: well ok, some memory is used, but it doesn't say which process is using it - you can open a terminal and type `top` or `htop` and see what process is hoarding your memory

Answer (score 1):

If the process ended then the memory should be freed, you can check what process is using memory by running utility such as `htop`.

when I have memory issues with python I often do following

```py
del memory_heavy_object_which_is_no_longer_needed

import gc
gc.collect()
```

Comment: how to free the ram now. After execution

Comment: if python process ends - memory should be freed, perhaps another process is using it, or, perhaps you measuring memory usage incorrectly - double-check that. restart the machine if you must.